# Oracle Different row counts using Join and without Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

I have an Oracle DB and use this query below to fetch records for a requirement. Five columns from three tables and a where condition.

```
select un.name, he.emp_no, he.lname, hr.in_unit, hr.out_unit
from hr_employee he
inner join hr_roster hr on he.eid = hr.eid
inner join units un on he.unit = un.unit_code
where hr.unit_date = to_date( '24-JUL-20','dd-MON-yy')
```

Later on I realize that if used in this way below, without Joins it is slightly faster.

```
select un.name, he.emp_no, he.lname, hr.in_unit, hr.out_unit
from hr_employee he, hr_roster hr, units un
where hr.unit_date = to_date( '24-JUL-20','dd-MON-yy')
```

But I notice that there's a difference of the rows getting fetched comparing the queries above.

When I took a row count of both queries, the one using Joins returns **1012** and the other one keeps fetching without a count.

I am bit confused and do not know which query is the most suitable to use.

Comment: Why do you think these always return the same thing?--Justifying per documentation. (They don't.) Please don't ask us to rewrite yet another presentation. Similarly what is your documentation-justified reason to claim the 2nd is "slightly faster"--in any cases you observed, and cases you didn't observe. (It isn't always.) If you don't clearly give your reasoning we can't address where you are going wrong or know what your actual question is. Also when you can't pin down your justifications you'll find your questions are faqs.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: The (incorrect) second query is another good example why you should never use the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins (hint: you are not using any joins in the second statement)

Comment: thanks @philipxy I was under the impression that the queries only differ syntax wise but there's more and determined the speed by the seconds for queries to fetch the rows (sql developer) which might not be quite professional :) maybe I stick to other online sources rather than irritating the professionals here.

Comment: You say the second one is 'slightly faster' but it 'keeps fetching without a count.' So it is not really faster :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Comma is cross join with lower precedence than keyword joins, your comment is a gross misrepresentation.

Comment: @philipxy the second query does not contain any join conditions that's why it's "incorrect" and does something completely different than the first query. It's impossible to "forget" the join condition using the "modern" (SQL-92) JOIN operator as that is a syntax error, not a "runtime" error producing wrong results. That's why the explicit JOINs should always be preferred and this question is another good example on how easily things like that happen with the "old" (SQL-89) implicit joins.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name x , y where c and d is a trivial syntactic variant of x join y on c where d. There is no more reason that special syntax is ergonomically critical for the specific case of operator inner join on than there is for, say, an operator join3 that needs to be used instead of join when wants the join of 3 tables so one doesn't forget a table. Morover since one has to already remember condition b in order to choose join on over cross join, your argument that on helps c not be forgotten is unsound. We disagree.

Answer (score 2):

The Second query treats as a `CROSS JOIN`, since there's no respective join conditions among those tables' columns, just exists a restriction due to a certain date, while the first one has a standard inner joins among tables with regular `INNER JOIN` conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The second query is basically incorrect as does not have join conditions on the second and 3rd table, except for a limitation on a date for the first table only. So it basically produces a cartesian product of the selected records from 1rst table times ALL records on 2nd table times ALL records on 3rd table.

The first query, which looks more correct, produces the selected records on 1rst table times the records on 2nd table joined by `he.eid = hr.eid` times the records on 3rd table joined by `he.unit = un.unit_code`